# Clipboard copy/paste from custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, clipboard, mediastore, custom-keyboard

I'm working hard on finding a solution on copy/paste images on input field of "other system apps"

In particular, I've created my own custom keyboard, within which I can press the emoji button. At this point, a panel is shown and a set of images (stored on device) are listed. On each image click, I'd like to paste the selected image in the current input field (p.e if the current app is any instant messaging like WApp, I want to paste my selected image on its input field).

The question is: I necessarily need to implement my own Content Provider (in order to let other app resolve correctly the uri of my images) or I can use Media Store provider available from OS?

Could you give me any suggestion in order to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In case of set emoji in IME so you just use a hex unicode of emoji like-

```
int keyCode = 0x1F60F;
getEmijoByUnicode(keyCode);
                    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(getEmijoByUnicode(keyCode), 1);
```

Use this method

```
public String getEmijoByUnicode(int unicode) {
            return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
        }
```